# SetBackground of ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listitem

I have to set the background of particular listView item to gray on a condition that isDelivered() and getPicked() both should be true.
For the first few listItems that shows up on opening the activity , the background is setting properly but once I scroll down, random items background is setting to gray, not obeying my condition.

(I feel its the position issue) but then my custom adapter class extends ArrayAdapter and the position on my logcat is also in correct order 0,1,2,3...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.custaddress, parent, false);
    }

    final View rowView = convertView;

    tripPickUp = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picked);
    tripDelivered = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delivered);
    tripIsDelivered = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.isdelivered);

    if (tripsheet[position].getPicked() == false
            && tripsheet[position].isDelivered() == false) {
        tripPickUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tripDelivered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tripIsDelivered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    else if (tripsheet[position].isDelivered() == false
            && tripsheet[position].getPicked() == true) {
        tripPickUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tripDelivered.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tripIsDelivered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else {
        tripDelivered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tripIsDelivered.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tripPickUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Basically the else statement is the condition that is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetView reuses the views. No matter the state it's in (or color), and they might not be the same as in the xml.

So basically you are setting some items to grey (when the conditions are true), and, when they get reused, you dont set them back to white.

Here's something to get you going:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.custaddress, parent, false);
    }

final View rowView = convertView;

tripPickUp = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picked);
tripDelivered = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delivered);
tripIsDelivered = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.isdelivered);

if (tripsheet[position].getPicked() == false
        && tripsheet[position].isDelivered() == false) {
    tripPickUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tripDelivered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tripIsDelivered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rowView.setBackgroundResource(Color.WHITE);
}

else if (tripsheet[position].isDelivered() == false
        && tripsheet[position].getPicked() == true) {
    tripPickUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tripDelivered.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tripIsDelivered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rowView.setBackgroundResource(Color.WHITE);

} else {
    tripDelivered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tripIsDelivered.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tripPickUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
}

return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because views are recycled by the adapter for performance reasons. If you make sure to set the background always, not only when it's supposed to be grey, you should be fine.

In other words, don't trust the views to have the initial state declared in xml, make sure to explicitly set all colors and other attributes that any item could change in any condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing:
Remove: `final View rowView = convertView;`

Rather than returning the `rowView` just return the `convertView`

and replace this

```
rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
```

by

```
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
```

I also faced the issue. I think making the rowView final is creating the problem.